# jailbreaking Iphone 2G in windows 7 and how to?

Tags: windows-7, iphone

Is there a tutorial on how to jailbreak iPhone 2G using windows 7? 
I can't find any software that is compatible with windows 7. I need some tutorials to fix my iphone and install some new and useful apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer to [Jailbreaking my iPod touch](https://superuser.com/questions/4668/jailbreaking-my-ipod-touch/55530#55530):

> There are a couple of different programs out there for jail breaking the iDevices, all with their different processes, pros and cons
>
> ## PwnageTool
>
> **Version 3.1.4, Mac OS X**
>
> PwnageTool creates a custom, jailbroken firmware to restore to your iPod. This is only really good if you have an iPhone and don't want to upgrade the baseband in order to do a carrier unlock, or if you want to reset your device and erase everything from it.
>
> **Latest compatible firmware:** 3.1.2
>   **Compatible devices:**
>
> - iPhone
> - iPhone 3G
> - iPod touch
> - iPod touch 2Gen<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup>Note: The 2nd gen iPod touch must be already jailbroken in order to accept the custom firmware. As a work around, install (and jailbreak) using 3.1, then use PwnageTool to update to the latest firmware</sup>
>
> ## Blackra1n
>
> **Mac OS X, Windows**
>
> Blackra1n is a new tool that claims to jailbreak your device in 30 seconds. It is very similar to the redsn0w or Quickpwn of yesteryear. It works by connecting an un-jailbroken device in and run the program. It will take like 5 seconds and reboot the device, and it is jailbroken. I have used this for my iPod touch and I am quite impressed by it.
>
> **Latest compatible firmware:** 3.1.2
>   **Compatible devices:**
>
> - iPhone
> - iPhone 3G
> - iPhone 3GS
> - iPod touch
> - iPod touch 2Gen
> - iPod touch 3Gen<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup>Note: Blackra1n is a tethered jailbreak for the third generation iPod touch. This means that every time you restart your device (which isn't really that often for most people) you have to connect it back to a computer and run Blackra1n again.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Unlock/Jailbreak Your iPhone 2G on OS 3.0.x Using RedSn0w (Windows)](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=4302) from iClarified.

Answer (score 0):

Use [blackra1n](http://blackra1n.com/).  Fastest and simplest thing out there. It is an executable that will complete in around a minute. I've used it several times.